# How to make a rounded background (grey transparant) behind the arrow button like twitter button on header?

Tags: android, button

I need to make a background behind my button that already have background (its like 2 layer background). it just like twitter header button for edit profile and back.

i already use android:background on first layer and styles on second layer. but the it just show one of them, not both.
this is my example button code:

```
<Button
    android:onClick="backDialog"
    style="@style/buttonBackStyle"
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_left_arrow_2"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:onClick="openEditScreen"
    android:id="@+id/btnEditPofile"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_edit_profile"
    android:gravity="end"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

i expected the button change like this

[image]

and what i got is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make a round drawable file in drawable folder

round_white.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <!-- solid background -->
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/_15sdp" />
            <!-- draw a border around rectangle shape-->
            <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#0575E6" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In your layout file use it like this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view_shadow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/edit" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. After modified it, its successfull. but can i make the effect from that? like button effect when clicked

Comment: you can use libraries for this.They are easily available on github

Comment: But you answer does not have the exact thing needed its just giving border no transparency for that drawable so just check it before you say anything

Comment: I have already used the same thing in my project so better dont copy answers and post it as yours and still if you suggest any change you would have commented on my post

Comment: but your code was not making it transparent providing a half solution is not a solution

Answer (score -1):

round_transparent.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <!-- solid background -->
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/_15sdp" />

            <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#4D212121" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In your layout file use it like this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view_shadow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
       >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/edit" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: copying my answer and posting it with slight modification,instead you would have supported my answer